# Button Click with Toggle Animate

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know this question has been asked before but I couldn't find the solution I needed.

I'm trying to make the '**product detail**' button on my website [here](https://www.simplylifting.co.uk/ridgegear-superglow-rescue-harness-rgh5-copy-2/) a 'show more / show less' toggle button with a background linear fade. Currently, clicking the button *animates* to reveal the details as I want but the button disappears and you can't toggle back to close it again.

This is my JQuery Code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
  $('#hiddenBlock').animate({height: '150px'});

  $('#showBlock').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
  $('#hiddenBlock').animate({height: '100%'}, "slow");
    });
    });
```

What am I missing?? I've tried using .toggle() instead of animate - that didn't work.

Comment: You don’t need $ sign in first line, also see this slideToggle example shown below if it’ll help https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_event_ready

Comment: I've gone through your link and found that your button is not hidden it is been pushed by your upper element , give `margin-top: -66px;` to `#showBlock` and you'll see it...

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate your question.
You can do one things that firstly you change text of button 
onclick rather hiding it:

```
$("button").on('click', function(){ 
  $(this).toggleClass("see-more"); 
});
$(".see-more").text("See Less");
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually your button is hiding behind the "You might Also like" div if you see in inspect tools. you need make its position up through **top: -100px or margin-top:-100px**  in #showBlock div